# Keycloak logout user from Authenticators (Backchannel logout)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

Is there any way to logout user all session after password change?
I tried to remove session from authentications / required actions using below code

```
List<UserSessionModel> sess =  context.getSession().sessions().getUserSessions(context.getRealm(),context.getUser());
        for (UserSessionModel ses : sess) {
            AuthenticationManager.backchannelLogout(context.getSession(),ses, false);
            AuthenticationManager.backchannelLogout(context.getSession(),ses, true);
}
```

Comment: Keycalok already removes the session for password change.

Comment: I am using version 4.1, but its not removing any session. I am using it in mobile device and web simultaneous, If I change password from web I am able to call logout by customizing ftl themes. But I need to logout mobile session also.

Comment: Are you able to browse through using mobile after password change in web ?

Comment: Yes I can browse using different medium / session. Need to trigger logout all sessions

Comment: I am using 4.8 version, and keycloak doesn't session on password change. I have worked with 4.5.0 and still the same. It is weird because once password is changed for a user it should iinvalidate all of its active sessions. Is there a flag or something I am missing ?